# how to remove id from URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My current URL is
http://localhost/news/user/user_profile/16

http://localhost/news = is base url

/user/ = is controller name

user_profile = is function name

this is link

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/user_profile/'.$id;?>" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
```

16  = is user id

I want to remove user id from URL

so i want my URL like this

http://localhost/news/user/user_profile

please help......

Comment: without user id how can you access the corresponding page ?

Comment: Where is the problem? Just remove «.$id» from your link.

Comment: you could use if statement `uri segment` 3 is true then show url or else shows user_profile.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If the `user_profile` functions needs the `id` of user, how you are going to provide that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you use.

If you want to show own profile or logged in user profile.
You can use the link. http://localhost/news/user/user_profile
where id will be the logged user id that will be in session..

In other case if you want to show the profile of another users like facebook profiles. You have to take  id or the slug in the url. It is the best method.

http://localhost/news/user/user_profile/(id) or
http://localhost/news/user/user_profile/(slug-name) or

Still you need to have url like http://localhost/news/user/user_profile/
means you have to use form for each and every link and submit the form for every request and take the id as post method which i will not recommend the way.